# How to get command line output snippet if I know the line number in Windows?

Tags: windows, shell, service, command-line, pipe

**SCENARIO :**

I am trying to find out a shell scripting way (a command line method) to find out the status of some specific windows service. For instance I picked up Telnet Service, it was in disabled mode (checked from services.msc) and won't come in `sc query` command.

`sc query state= all` worked fine and delivered me the list of all services (active/inactive). Now my problem is reduced to find out a way to get the service status from windows service display name (output piping).

I tried  `sc query state= all | find /N "Telnet"` but this would only give me the search line no and its content, not the service status as that information is 2-3 lines ahead of display name (where it is searched and returned by pipe).

**PROBLEM :**

Is there a way in windows to pipe output from line number position ? Like in my case, if telnet service is found at line no:182, to give me the command output from line no: 180 to 187 ??

Feel free to let me know of any better way to solve my problem if you got any ideas.

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is PowerShell an option?  That's built into recent Windows versions and will get your service status in a simple command.  If the service display name was Windows Time

```
get-service -DisplayName "windows time" | Select-Object Status
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it with a batch file, although it's not a very elegant solution.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set currentservice=""
set servicestate=""
sc query state= all > services.txt
for /f "delims=:; tokens=1,2" %%a in (services.txt) do call :findservice "%%a" "%%b"
del services.txt

echo %servicestate%

endlocal
goto :end

:findservice
if not %1 == "SERVICE_NAME" goto :findstate
set currentservice=%2
goto :end

:findstate
if not %1 == "        STATE              " goto :end
if not %currentservice% == " Telnet" goto :end
set servicestate=%2
goto :end

:end
```

It first writes out the result of the `sc query` to a temporary file (services.txt). It then uses a for loop to process each line of that file.

When it find a line starting with `SERVICE_NAME`, it saves the value of that name in the *currentservice* variable. Then when it finds a line starting with `STATE`, if the *currentservice* variable is set to `" Telnet"` it saves the value of the state in the *servicestate* variable.

So at the end of it all, you should have some kind of state in the *servicestate* variable (which I'm echoing in the example code). This will be something like `" 4  RUNNING "` or `" 1  STOPPED "`. If the Telnet service is not found, it'll be blank.

Note that spaces in the code are all significant because of the way the sc query output is processed. In particular, note that the service name you are trying to match must start with a space.

It's possible this could be improved, but at least it's a start.

Comment: I do not see any output except "" running the provided script in my computer ! Further as already tested sc query gives information about only running services. It hides inactive/diabled service states.

Comment: @AviMehenwal If the Telnet service isn't listed in the `sc query` then that's exactly what I would expect it to show. I don't know of any other way to list services. If that's not the problem, then that probably means I got the name wrong in this line: `if not %currentservice% == " Telnet" goto :end`. You can just add an `echo %currentservice% %2` on the line before that to see the name and state of everything if you want to work out what name to use.

Answer (score 1):

@dbenham wrote a tool called repl.bat which can be found at at http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

Using it in the manner below it provides a list of the processes and state:

```
sc query | findstr "SERVICE_NAME STATE" | repl "SERVICE_NAME..(.*)\r\n" "$1" m  | repl "(.*) *STATE.*:....(.*)." "$2 - $1"
```

This is a sample of the output under Win 8 Pro 32 bit

RUNNING - wcncsvc
RUNNING - WdiServiceHost
RUNNING - WinDefend
RUNNING - WinHttpAutoProxySvc
RUNNING - winmgmt
RUNNING - WPDBusEnum
RUNNING - wscsvc

and to get a full list of all services with service and display name, this works here:

```
sc query state= all | findstr "DISPLAY_NAME: SERVICE_NAME STATE" | repl "SERVICE_NAME..(.*)\r\n" "$1" m  | repl "DISPLAY_NAME:.(.*)\r\n" " - $1" m | repl "(.*) *STATE.*: .  (.*)."  "$2 - $1"
```

Which provides a list like this:

RUNNING - WPDBusEnum - Portable Device Enumerator Service
RUNNING - wscsvc - Security Center
STOPPED - WSearch - Windows Search
STOPPED - WSService - Windows Store Service (WSService)
STOPPED - wuauserv - Windows Update
STOPPED - wudfsvc - Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework
STOPPED - WwanSvc - WWAN AutoConfig

Comment: I am not looking for any 3rd party tool to do my job right now because its only a small portion of my tool I am currently working on. I need something I understand from root till tip so that I could modify that later. Thanks for help @foxidrive :)

Comment: @Avi Mehenwal That's ok, but repl.bat is a batch file that uses windows scripting host and standard jscript regexp.  You need to be able to understand the regexp to some degree to use it but it's a very useful tool.  It's not third party any more than any batch file is...

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method.  I took some shortcuts which make it a bit slower but it should run on all Windows versions that have SC I expect.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('sc query state^= all ^| findstr "DISPLAY_NAME: STATE" ') do (
echo %%a|find "DISP">nul && set /p "=%%b : "<nul
echo %%a|find "STATE">nul && (set /p "=%%b"<nul&echo.)
)
pause
```

Here is the output:

Family Safety : 1  STOPPED
Portable Device Enumerator Service : 4  RUNNING
Security Center : 4  RUNNING
Windows Search : 1  STOPPED
Windows Store Service (WSService) : 1  STOPPED
Windows Update : 1  STOPPED
Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework : 1  STOPPED
WWAN AutoConfig : 1  STOPPED

Comment: Its very slow comparative to repl.bat ;) Is there no way I can pipe outputs using line no range in windows ??? This is what exactly what I am looking right now.

Comment: You can pipe the output to a file and number the lines using find, and then use findstr to detect which line has your search term on to extract the number in a loop, and use another forINdo loop to parse and extract the term you need.  Yes, it can be done.  @Aacini would read it all into an array and manipulate that to get the term - but it's convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code to give you two lines above the display_name line, assuming the match to your query is in the display_name line.

"%1" is the service name you are after - make the term unique too.

```
@echo off
set "n=-1"
sc query state= all |findstr /n "^" >Log.tmp
for /f "delims=:" %%a in (' findstr /i "%~1" ^<log.tmp ') do set n=%%a
set /a n=n+2
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' findstr /i "^%n%:" ^<log.tmp ') do set "line=%%a"
echo "%line%"
del log.tmp
pause
```